# Floating elements not working when using px & %

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a simple structure, but i'm struggling with the concept of this.

I have an `aside` that has a fixed width of 255px. I have a `main` that i want to occupy 100% of the remaining width (after the 255px from the `aside`). The website doesn't have a containing width, this is designed to fill the entire screen space available. Is anyone able to help, here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/tooqderr/).

HTML:

```
<aside>
    <p>Text</p>
</aside>
<main>
    <p>Main Text</p>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
aside { width: 255px; float: left; background: red; }
main { width: 100%; float: left; background: blue; }
```

I'm sure it's simple, and i'm sure im approaching this the wrong way but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove `float: left;` from `main`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, that will just make `main` wrap around the `aside` when it is too long.

If you don't mind removing the 255px from the aside, you can set the aside to 32%, main to 67%, and a container element with a width of 800px. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/tooqderr/2/

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek ah ha! This has worked on the fiddle fine. Just trying to apply it to my actual site and hitting a few snags. Bear with me :)

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper Your example doesn't fit the remaining space

Comment: @AndyHolmes, If you don't mind removing the hard-coded 255px, this does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/tooqderr/4/

Comment: I need the fixed width unfortunately

Comment: This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/tooqderr/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67780/discussion-between-theirondeveloper-and-andy-holmes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different solutions. The one I think you want the most is absolutely positioning the aside, and applying a margin to the main:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container{position:relative;}
aside { width: 255px; position:absolute; background: red; }
main { margin-left: 255px; background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <aside>
        <p>Text</p>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <p>Main Text</p>
        <p>Main Text</p>
        <p>Main Text</p>
    </main>
</div>
```

Several other people mentioned killing the float on main, that will work, but overflowing content from main will wrap under the aside, which I don't believe you want.

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
aside { width: 255px; float: left; background: red; }
main { width: 100%; background: blue; }
```

```html
<aside>
    <p>Text</p>
</aside>
<main>
    <p>Main Text</p>
    <p>Main Text</p>
    <p>Main Text</p>
</main>
```

The 3rd solution doesn't work any more, because the 255px aside is a hard requirement, but it is:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container {width: 100%; background: blue; overflow:hidden;}
aside { width: 32%; float: left; background: red; }
main { width: 67%; float: left;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <aside>
        <p>Text</p>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <p>Main Text</p>
        <p>Main Text</p>
        <p>Main Text</p>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Easy way of fixing the problem with text overflow: add `padding-left: 255px;` to `main`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek is absolutely right, it would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/tooqderr/8/

Comment: It's 2:40 AM, i blame sleep deprivation haha. padding-left fixed a lot of issues after i dropped the float left. Thanks every one

Answer (score 2):

Remove the float from main or go by % for both aside and main.

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
aside { width: 30%; float: left; background: red; }
main { width: 70%; float: left; background: blue; }
```

```html
<aside>
    <p>Text</p>
</aside>
<main>
    <p>Main Text</p>
</main>
```

**Solution 2:** apply the blue background to the body instead. That way, main won't be a big issue.

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: blue; }
aside { width: 255px; float: left; background: red; }
main { width: auto; padding-left: 100px ; float: left; background: inherot; }
```

```html
<aside>
    <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
</aside>
<main>
    <p>Main Text</p>
   <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
</main>
```

Comment: I need to use the fixed width on the aside

Comment: Then kill the float for main.

Comment: padding-left on `main` sorted it by the looks of it :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes when I used inspect element, I added position: absolute; z-index: 99999; to aside and it fixed it. so leave it the way you have it now and add those to it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `float` from `main` will do the trick, I've also added some `padding` on `main p`:

```
aside { 
    width: 255px; 
    float: left; 
    background: red; 
}

main { 
    width: 100%; 
    background: yellow; 
}

main p { 
    padding: 15px; 
}
```